# How to run app engine unit tests in pycharm?

Tags: google-app-engine, unit-testing

I'm trying to run the following test ile

```
from google import appengine
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

import unittest
import passwordproperty

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tb = testbed.Testbed()
        self.tb.setup_env()
        self.tb.activate()
        self.tb.init_datastore_v3_stub()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.tb.deactivate()

    ... tests ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But when I try to run this file, I get the following error:

```
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind localhost:8080
```

So it looked like something was almready using port 8080, so I ran `lsof -i :8080`, which came up empty, and navigating to localhost without a port also doesn't give me anything. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the run/debug configuration create project of "python tests"  and set the values like working directory , class (class name of the test class) and it will work